# Meaning of "early neurotoxicity" in description of methotrexate treatment effects - at an early age? or an early-stage neurotoxicity?

Tags: cancer, terminology, neurology, toxicity

From a [guideline](https://doi.org/10.1186/s13023-020-01379-8):

> Due to the inhibitory effect of methotrexate on DHPR and the interaction with dihydrofolate reductase (DHFR), this treatment may lead to HPA and **early neurotoxicity**, possibly combined with folate deficiency [153].

What is the meaning of "early neurotoxicity"? An early-stage neurotoxicity that has not yet progressed to a more severe form? Or a neurotoxicity at an early age, meaning that methotrexate should be avoided in children? Or a neurotoxicity that developed too early for the person's age, "a neurotoxicity that is untypical because it developed too early"?

[Reference 153](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/1793349/) leads to an article in French, so it's hard for me to understand the meaning. I'm a Russian.

### References

Netter, J. C., Dhondt, J. L., Rance, F., & Petrus, M. (1991). Neurotoxicité précoce du méthotrexate à haute dose et déficit en tétrahydrobioptérine [Early neurotoxicity of high-dose of methotrexate and tetrahydrobiopterin deficiency]. *Archives francaises de pediatrie, 48*(10), 719–722. https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/1793349/

Opladen, T., López-Laso, E., Cortès-Saladelafont, E., Pearson, T. S., Sivri, H. S., Yildiz, Y., ... & Hübschmann, O. K. (2020). Consensus guideline for the diagnosis and treatment of tetrahydrobiopterin (BH4) deficiencies. *Orphanet Journal of Rare Diseases, 15*(126). https://doi.org/10.1186/s13023-020-01379-8

Comment: I have found Google translate to be hit and miss, on its ability to accurately translate foreign text but have you tried using [Google Translate](https://translate.google.co.uk/) or Microsoft Translate [website](https://www.bing.com/translator) or [Windows/Mac/iOS/Android app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/)?

Comment: @ChrisRogers - I regularly use Google Translate, it has been getting better by leaps and bounds in the last several years. I just want to be on the safe side when translating a medical text ))) I found several Russian texts where a word-for-word translation of "ранняя нейротоксичность" is used, but it is ambiguous too, so I want to know the true meaning.